# How to troubleshoot failing cron job

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, scheduling

I have a `crontab` `root` file that looks like this:

```
lab-1:/var/www/cdd# crontab -l
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day     month   weekday command
*       *       *       *       *       /etc/scripts/script1
*/15    *       *       *       *       /etc/scripts/script2
0       *       *       *       *       /etc/scripts/script3
```

I can see that all the jobs are triggered by running this command:

```
lab-1:/var/www/cdd# cat /var/log/messages | grep cron.info
Mar 15 13:00:00 lab-1 cron.info crond[7897]: USER root pid 26217 cmd /etc/scripts/script2
Mar 15 13:00:00 lab-1 cron.info crond[7897]: USER root pid 26219 cmd /etc/scripts/script3        
Mar 15 13:01:00 lab-1 cron.info crond[7897]: USER root pid 26293 cmd /etc/scripts/script1
```

The problem is that script3 (I've proven that script2 and script1 work) is not actually producing the expected output.  It's supposed to create files in another folder. 
However, when I run it manually like so, it works just fine:

```
 lab-1:/etc/scripts# bash script3
```

I'm not a real sys admin so not too sure what the best way is to go about troubleshooting this.

First thing that comes to mind is permissions.

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# ls -lah                            
total 24                                                                     
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Mar 15 12:20 .                     
drwxr-xr-x   34 root     root        4.0K Mar 14 17:11 ..                    
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        5.0K Mar 15 12:19 script3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.8K Mar 14 15:26 script1
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.9K Mar 14 15:26 script2
```

Although... having said that, if it were a permissions problem would it even show up as being triggered / started in my `/var/log/messages` file?

How should I proceed?

**EDIT 1**

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# ./script3 | head -n 4                                             
Working folder set to: /tmp/tmp.kOfhip                                                                        
*****Grab SQL Data from Remote Server: spp.mydomain.net *****                                             
COPY 344                                                                                                      
Warning: Permanently added 'spp.mydomain.net,10.1.1.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.           
Evaluate /tmp/tmp.kOfhip/spp.mydomain.net.db                                                          
lab-1:/etc/scripts#
```

**EDIT 2**

This is what my script looks like:

https://paste.pound-python.org/show/90vAlrOsAYP0CtYqNWfl/

As you can see, I'm creating a temporary folder and doing all my work in there.

**EDIT 3**

To prove to myself that it's not because of lines like line 9, I've commented out everything except lines 1 though 15.  I added line 16 that does this:

```
 echo "done" >> /tmp/results.txt
```

ANd then I changed the schedule of the job to run every two minutes from one hour.  i can see that it's run 3 times already.
I guess I will continue with this approach until I find something that won't work / blows up.
I don't quite understand the comment made below about using a PATH variable... but I guess I will google it.

**EDIT 4**

I changed the crontabs root file so it outputs the results of script3 to a file and this is what i see:

```
Working folder set to: /tmp/tmp.GeNGDJ
*****Grab SQL Data from Remote Server: servername *****
COPY 344
Warning: Permanently added 'spp.mydomain.net,10.1.1.132' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
Evaluate /tmp/tmp.GeNGDJ/spp.mydomain.net.db
cat: can't open '/tmp/tmp.GeNGDJ/spp.mydomain.net.db': No such file or directory
```

So it's dying while trying to scp the file.  The remote SQL runs just fine and shows output.  But as you can see I'm getting a permission denied
But if i run the same command manually, it seems to work. 
Will have to keep poking around.  Will try dumping the ENV like is suggested in the answer below.

Comment: please [edit] your question, and add the content of `script3`. It might be useful to compare it to `script1` or `script2` which seems to work.

Comment: What's going on when you try to run script3 in this way: go to /etc/scripts directory and do `./script3`. Could you provide output `head -n 4 script3`?

Comment: @mariaczi please see EDIT 1  in my original question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Yaron I actually haven't proven yet that script 1 or 2 works.  I'm in the middle of doing that now... since I've discovered that script3 for sure doesn't work.  will post an update once I know.

Comment: The usual mistakes are a) use of relative instead of absolute path names, b) assume a working directory. When you tried `bash script3` your CWD is `/etc/scripts` but when cron starts a script it's CWD is usualy / however it's not defined, so use absolute path names. To test this `cd / ; bash /etc/scripts/script3` and see what your script does.

Comment: @dot you don't understood me correctly, but from your "EDIT1" see, that when you run this script manually, it work ok. Please check in, if you use absolute path for all commands running from system as cron not have PATH environment variable.

Comment: @XTian sorry you want me to try that on the command line?  Cuz it works just fine when I do.

Comment: @XTian i'm going to post my code in a pastebin.  But I'm creating a tmp folder and doing everything from there .

Comment: @mariaczi i will post the script code in one sec.

Comment: @mariaczi ok please see EDIT 2

Comment: @XTian please see EDIT 2

Comment: @Yaron the other two scripts do work.

Comment: As we told earlier, you use dig, awk, sed for example, without absolute path for it. You could set PATH variable on the beginning of your script, but after first line or use absolute path for this mentioned by me binaries and rest other which you use.

Comment: @mariaczi sorry for being thick.  I'm really not a sys admin or good with this stuff.  I can count on my one hand the number of bash scripts I've written.  But please, correct me if I'm wrong.  The dig command can be run from anywhere. It's not dependant on being in a specific folder.  So I'm not following why you're picking on line 9 for example.  If anything, I would think your comments would apply to lines where I'm copying things from one location to another?  Not sure.  Can you explain a little bit more? Or give me a practical example of how it might fail so I can look for those things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common mistake when writing scripts that will be executed later by cron, is that you assume the script will have exactly the same environment that you have when you are logged in and you are developing it. It hasn't!

Write a script4 which contains the following line

```
OFILE=/tmp/crons.environment
(/usr/bin/whoami
/usr/bin/env ) > $OFILE 2>&1
```

And get cron to run that

Now compare the output in /tmp/crons.environment to what you get when you
just type `env`

Your script assumes for example that $PATH is setup correctly to find all the programs you execute, you are also querying a database, there could be further Environment variables required for those commands to run correctly.

To check the output from the cron job. Temporarily modify the command run by cron and redirect stdout and stderr to a known file, Like I did above.

```
0       *       *       *       *       /etc/scripts/script3 > /tmp/s3.out 2>&1
```

Comment: i love the last tip... about directing the output!  cool.  i'll give that a try right now!!  Thank you!!  +1 just for suggesting that to me.  Very useful as a troubleshooting tip ... which is really what I'm looking for.

Comment: XTian, please see EDIT 4.  Now that I have the output dumping successfully to a file, I'm going to check the env stuff as you suggest.  Thanks.

Comment: Marking this as the answer although i haven't found the fix.  I think you've just taught me how to fish.  Thanks!